# Backlit keyboard light keeps turning on by itself on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I recently installed Linux Mint 18.3 'Sylvia' on my ASUS ZenBook UX330U. Apparently the system is turning toggling the backlit light for many reasons. Sometimes I turn up the light on the screen and it turns on, other times it turns on when it gets dark. How do I change the settings so that it only turns on when I use the Hotkeys?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it using an answer provided [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/keyboard-light-keeps-turning-on-after-login-and-or-unlock/6914/12).

Basically you need to edit `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UPower.conf` and replace

`<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>`

to

`<deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>`

Comment: I have an Asus Q304UAK laptop with the same problem. Unfortunately the fix also breaks the Power Manager and disables the screen brightness function keeys. Up vote for getting close to the fix.